# Is the adoption of IS0 9000 principles, or even actual ISO certification very common in universities?

Tags: lab-management, management

I'm not sure if this is on-topic but nothing seemed conclusive that it wasn't in the help center, so let's see what happens.

The [ISO 9000 family of standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9000) has been adopted by well over a million organizations in the world, most of them are of course businesses with customers, but not all of them are.

I'd like to know if the adoption of IS0 9000 principles, or even actual ISO certification is very common in universities.

The two areas I'm interested in are

1. Large science efforts that handle substantial funding, where the standardization of procedures might improve efficiency of use of funds and project completion
2. Universities of no particular size or areas of research, but where the procedures are of a *departmental nature* i.e. paperwork, human resources, departmental budgets and management, etc.

My guess is that there may indeed be some adoption in the first category and only small, scattered or isolated instances of the second, but it's only a guess.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I believe that the purpose of Stack Exchange is to work in a collaborative way to generate good answers to on-topic questions. By asking thousands of Stack Exchange questions I hope to do my part to facilitate that. Thank you for [doing yours](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/153439/69206)!

Comment: Universities have to go through a periodic accreditation process, which has roughly the same function. See for example https://sacscoc.org/ for an organization that performs accreditation audits.

Comment: Where I was doing my PhD, Tyndall National Institute (an Irish research institute associated to a university), I remember admin circulating emails about some inspection related to ISO certification. I don't know if they got it or already had it, but they were certainly striving to be certified.

Comment: Not an answer because I don't have the necessary familiarity with relevant literature to back up an answer, but some of the quality management principles would be deeply problematic in a university context.  Universities' external "customers" are not qualified to specify requirements, "unity of purpose" runs counter to the ethos of independent, self-governing scholars, many university processes are fundamentally _not_ interrelated and understanding them as interrelated would be an error, etc.

Comment: @DanielHatton Don't you think that *students* are customers? Don't they provide cash and expect something of value in return? What about agencies that provide funding for research (equipment, travel, staff salaries, etc.)? Don't they expect that the funds are managed well, spent in appropriate and accountable ways to further specific, stated goals? Modern universities are more than just places to further the "ethos of independent, self-governing scholars" these days. They're not just hotels for smart people to sit around and think independently and express themselves whenever they see fit.

Comment: @DanielHatton anyway, just because some aspects fo ISO standardization might require customer-specified standards doesn't mean the adoption of some ISO *principles* (as asked about here) is impossible. For example, one aspect might include 1) standard procedures for doing things exist, that 2) these procedures are documented, that 3) they are followed, and that 4) there's a mechanism to verify and ensure they are followed. How would those, applied to things like money, record-keeping/privacy, human resources, etc. run counter to  the "ethos of independent, self-governing scholars" these days?

Comment: @uhoh 1. I specifically said *some* of the QM principles are problematic, not *all* of them. 2. It's an explicit policy of most universities here in the UK not to refer to students as customers, and I endorse that policy. 3. Even if you do consider students as customers, presumably you wouldn't let them design the learning outcomes of degree programmes, which is where the "customer focused" principle points. 4. Funding agencies rely on external peer-reviewers to allocate resources because they recognise that they don't know how to do effective (as opposed to efficient) research.

Answer (score 1):

I know of one university which is ISO 9001 certified.  Most universities are not.  I have not been able to discern any benefit to the certification.  I am not aware of any "science effort" that is certified.

Comment: Various DOE national labs (US) have a range of ISO certifications.